# Can I disable running shell commands in Vim?

Tags: external-command, options

I am developing a command line application that uses Vim to edit an existing file. Think `visudo` or `crontab -e`.

Is there any command line option that I can pass to Vim to disable shell commands?

Comment: Could you provide some more detail about what you're trying to do, to demonstrate the problem?  What is being escaped, and why don't you want it escaped?

Comment: Just FYI, the term "shell escaping" is usually used in Vim to refer to the practice of altering string-format commands in order that they are interpreted correctly by the shell. See `:help shellescape()`. What I think you're talking about is usually referred to as "shell commands" or sometimes "shelling out".

Answer (score 2):

The `-Z` (restricted mode) command line option is what I'm looking for. This provides sufficient protection against `:!` being used. Thanks to [Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343/rich) and [B Layer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/11054/b-layer) for pointing this out in my sister question, "[Prevent saving buffer with new name](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15100/prevent-saving-buffer-with-new-name)"